# How to find the position of a Rectangle in a Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, rectangles

I'm trying to create a Bricks in WPF C#, but I can't find the position of my rectangles in a grid.

I need the coordinates of the rectangles to implement the collisions and add points when break the brick, but I can't find any function to find the position from the `cs`.

**MainWindows.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="gioco.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:gioco"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Bricks" Height="450" Width="813" Loaded="window_Loaded"
        PreviewKeyDown="Chiusura">
    <Canvas x:Name="playground" Background="Black" MouseMove="MouseMoving" Cursor="Arrow">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Player" Height="10" Canvas.Left="330" Stroke="White" Canvas.Top="390" Width="141"  Fill="#FFD8EDFF"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="ball" Height="14" Canvas.Left="393" Stroke="White" Canvas.Top="340" Width="14" Fill="#FFD8EDFF"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="boxOver" Canvas.Left="187" Canvas.Top="107" Text="Game Over!" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="146" Width="420" FontSize="72" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Arial Rounded MT Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Punti" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="39" Width="91" Foreground="White" FontSize="24"/>
        <Button x:Name="butStart" Content="S t a r t" Canvas.Left="223" Canvas.Top="107" Height="183" Width="354" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Bold" Click="butStart_Click" Margin="0,-2,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="HP1" Height="23" Canvas.Left="755" Canvas.Top="338" Width="23" Fill="#FFC80000" RadiusX="11.5" RadiusY="11.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-89.743"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="27.874" Y="28"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle x:Name="HP2" Height="23" Canvas.Left="783" Canvas.Top="338" Width="23" Fill="#FFC80000" RadiusX="11.5" RadiusY="11.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-89.743"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle x:Name="HP3" Height="23" Canvas.Left="811" Canvas.Top="338" Width="23" Fill="#FFC80000" RadiusX="11.5" RadiusY="11.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-89.743"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-27.874" Y="-28"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Grid x:Name="GridBlocks" Height="253" Width="800">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        </Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="boxRestart" Canvas.Left="252" Canvas.Top="197" Text="Press Space to restart" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="29" Width="296" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Bold" Foreground="White"/>

    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

**MainWindows.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace gioco
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Rectangle[,] rectangle = new Rectangle[20, 23];
        Timer timer1 = new Timer(20);
        int ballY = 0;
        int ballX = 0;
        int BallSpeedX = 2;
        int BallSpeedY = 2;
        double PlayerX;
        double PlayerY;
        int score = 0;
        int life = 3;
        bool inizio = false;
        bool pausa = false;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GridBlocks.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        private void window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ball.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Player.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            boxRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            //prepara il campo di gioco e avvia il timer
            PlayerX = (playground.ActualWidth / 2) - (Player.ActualWidth / 2);  //imposta la posizione del giocatore
            PlayerY = playground.ActualHeight - Player.ActualHeight - 20;       //imposta la posizione del giocatore
            Canvas.SetTop(Player, PlayerY);                                     //sistema la racchetta alle coordinate Y scelte
            Canvas.SetLeft(Player, PlayerX);                                    //sistema la racchetta alle coordinate X scelte
            boxOver.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;                         //gamer over reso invisibile
            //posiziona pallina a centro schermo
            ballX = (int)(playground.ActualWidth / 2);
            ballY = (int)(playground.ActualHeight / 2);
            HP1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            HP2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            HP3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
                {
                    rectangle[i, j] = new Rectangle();
                    GridBlocks.Children.Add(rectangle[i, j]);
                    Grid.SetRow(rectangle[i, j], i);
                    Grid.SetColumn(rectangle[i, j], j);
                    rectangle[i, j].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                    rectangle[i, j].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                    rectangle[i, j].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 216, 237, 255));
                }

            }

        }
        private void moveBallTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ballY += BallSpeedY;
            ballX += BallSpeedX;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(ball, ballY);
                Canvas.SetLeft(ball, ballX);
                Punti.Text = score.ToString(); //visualizza punti
            });

            //pallina contro bordo left
            if (ballX <= 0)
            {
                //inverte direzione X
                BallSpeedX = -BallSpeedX;
            }
            //pallina contro bordo right
            if ((ballX + ball.ActualWidth) >= playground.ActualWidth)
            {
                //inverte direzione X
                BallSpeedX = -BallSpeedX;
            }
            //pallina contro bordo top
            if (ballY <= 0)
            {
                //inverte direzione Y
                BallSpeedY = -BallSpeedY;
            }
            //pallina sotto racchetta
            if ((ballY + ball.ActualHeight) >= playground.ActualHeight)
            {
                life--;
                timer1.Stop();
                PlayerX = (playground.ActualWidth / 2) - (Player.ActualWidth / 2);
                PlayerY = playground.ActualHeight - Player.ActualHeight - 20;
                ballX = (int)(playground.ActualWidth / 2);
                ballY = (int)(playground.ActualHeight / 2);
                inizio = true;
                if (life <= 2)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        HP1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                    });
                    ballX = (int)(playground.ActualWidth / 2);
                    ballY = (int)(playground.ActualHeight / 2);
                }
                if (life <= 1) 
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                        HP2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    });
                    ballX = (int)(playground.ActualWidth / 2);
                    ballY = (int)(playground.ActualHeight / 2);
                }
                if (life <= 0)
                {
                    ballX = (int)(playground.ActualWidth / 2);
                    ballY = (int)(playground.ActualHeight / 2);
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                        HP3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    });
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        ball.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    });
                    //game over
                    timer1.Stop();
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
                    {
                        boxOver.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        boxRestart.Visibility = Visibility;
                        Player.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                        inizio = true;
                    });
                }
            }

            //pallina contro blocco
            if ((ballY + ball.ActualHeight) >= PlayerY
            && (((ballX + ball.ActualWidth) >= PlayerX
            && (ballX + ball.ActualWidth) <= (PlayerX + Player.ActualWidth))
            || (ballX >= PlayerX && ballX <= (PlayerX + Player.ActualWidth))))
            {
                BallSpeedX++;
                BallSpeedY++;
                BallSpeedY = -BallSpeedY;
                score += 10; //10 punti ogni volta che racchetta tocca pallina
            }
        }

        private void MouseMoving(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
            PlayerX = position.X;
            Canvas.SetLeft(Player, PlayerX);
        }
        private void Chiusura(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                pausa = !pausa;
                if (pausa)
                {
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                }
                else
                {
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
                }
                
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Space)
            {
                if (inizio)
                {
                    boxRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    boxOver.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    Player.Visibility = Visibility;
                    ball.Visibility = Visibility;
                    HP1.Visibility = Visibility;
                    HP2.Visibility = Visibility;
                    HP3.Visibility = Visibility;
                    Punti.Visibility = Visibility;
                    score = 0;
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                    if (life == 3)
                        HP1.Visibility = Visibility;
                    if (life >= 2)
                        HP2.Visibility = Visibility;
                    if (life >= 1)
                        HP3.Visibility = Visibility;
                    BallSpeedX = 2;
                    BallSpeedY = 2;
                    inizio = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void butStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            butStart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            timer1.Elapsed += moveBallTimer_Tick;
            ball.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Player.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
            inizio = true;
            HP1.Visibility = Visibility;
            HP2.Visibility = Visibility;
            HP3.Visibility = Visibility;
            GridBlocks.Visibility = Visibility;
            Algoritmo.CreaNuovoLivello(rectangle);
        }

        private void butStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;

        }
    }
}
```

**Algoritmo.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace gioco
{
    static class Algoritmo
    {
        
        public static bool ControlloFine(Rectangle[,] rectangles)
        {
            bool c = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
                {
                    if (rectangles[i, j].Visibility != System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden)
                    {
                        c = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!c)
                    break;
            }
            return c;
        }

        public static void CreaNuovoLivello(Rectangle[,] rectangles)
        {
            Random random = new();
            int e = random.Next(0,4);
            bool c = true;
            switch (e)
            {
                case 0:
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        c = !c;
                        for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
                        {
                            if (c)
                            {
                                rectangles[i, j].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                rectangles[i, j].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                                rectangles[1,2].
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 1:
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        c = !c;
                        for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
                        {
                            if (c)
                            {
                                rectangles[i, j].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                rectangles[i, j].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                            }
                            c = !c;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    c = !c;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
                        {
                            if (c)
                            {
                                rectangles[i, j].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                rectangles[i, j].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                            }
                            c = !c;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    int d = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
                        {
                            if (c || d > 2)
                            {
                                rectangles[i, j].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                                d++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                rectangles[i, j].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                                d = 0;
                            }
                            c = !c;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    int f = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
                        {
                            if (f < 3)
                            {
                                rectangles[i, j].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                rectangles[i, j].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                                if (f == 3)
                                    f = 0;
                            }
                            f++;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just positioning rectangles on the canvas without any transformation?  In games, it's usual to do calculations based on integer approximations. Eg calculate the line of pixels between each corner and the rest of a block or wall. Maybe the fifth one. I use a bresenham implementation for our game.  Giving a list of integer x,y. You can the calculate approx distance of the centre point of a ball to the nearest. There are integer based approximations which make each calculation faster. Optimise further by retaining the nearest from the last calculation and short circuit if distant

Comment: If you've got lots of bricks you can also calculate distance ball centre to brick centre and exclude bricks a long way off.

Comment: What's the game intended to do?

Answer (score -1):

t would have been nice if you had been able to reduce the code to a minimal working example where we can focus on the collision part alone.

Because of this I'm not able to help you to improve your code (it looks like it needs some. Multidimensional arrays, nested loops etc.). For example, you likely should use the `DispatcherTimer` configured with a reasonable `DispatcherPriority`. But I can show how you can check for the collision of two `Shape` objects:

```cs
var firstRectangleShape = new Rectangle();
var secondRectangleShape = new Rectangle();
Rect firstRectangeleShapeBounds = firstRectangleShape.RenderedGeometry.Bounds;
Rect secondRectangeleShapeBounds = secondRectangleShape.RenderedGeometry.Bounds;
bool hasCollision = firstRectangeleShapeBounds.IntersectsWith(secondRectangeleShapeBounds);
```

As long you have the bounding rectangle of the geometry, you can use this solution to detect collision between any kind of shape.
Alternatively, you would have to check if any of the (e.g. outline) points of shape_X is located inside the (outline) bounds of shape_Y.